# Avoid an overridden `val` being initialised in the base trait?

Tags: scala

In the following code:

```
trait Base {
  val foo: String = {
    println("Hi, I'm initializing foo in trait Base")
    "foo"
  }

}

class Overrider extends Base {
  override val foo = "bar!"
}

object Runner extends App {
  println(new Overrider().foo)
  println((new {override val foo = "baz"} with Base).foo)
}
```

`Base` trait's `foo` value initialisation is called regardless of whether I override the *val* by extending the trait or using an early initialiser:

```
Hi, I'm initializing foo in trait Base
bar!
Hi, I'm initializing foo in trait Base
baz
```

Is there a way to use `val`s and avoid that happening or should I just stick with `lazy val`s?

Comment: I think that if you don't want the trait `Base` value `foo` to be evaluated you will have to change it to a function `def`. What are you trying to do with the value in the trait? Are you trying to have a default value?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin it's in a wiring module (one like shown in an example here http://di-in-scala.github.io/#modules) and I wanted to enforce eager evaluation, but still allow for overriding the value in tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `lazy val` as you mentioned or `def`. AFAIK there is no other way to avoid the initialization of `val`s in base classes. This is because everything outside class member definitions goes into the constructor. Therefore `val`s will be initialized on construction time.

Another approach would be to define an interface which you extend from:

```
trait Base {
  def foo: String
}

class Foo extends Base {
  override val foo = "foo"
}

class Bar extends Base {
  override val foo = "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users answered to your question, you have to define `foo` as a `def` if you do not want the `Base` trait method being valuated.

You told to me in the comments of your question that you were trying to implement a *wiring module*, as the one described in this [link](http://di-in-scala.github.io/#modules). Then, you're basically trying to implement  the **thin cake pattern**.

In this case, it is not logically correct to declare `foo` as a `val`. `foo` represents a dependency that cannot be eagerly resolved . If you use a `val`, the two components will be tight coupled. You've to define `foo` as a `def` to let to your main application (or test) to wire `foo` to the correct type, i.e. a concrete class or a mock.

Let me know if you want some more explanations.